# TypeError: firebase_firestore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.doc.data is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

this is where problem is arising here getting data from the firebase

```
      14 | useEffect(() => {
      15 |   const q = query(collection(db, "posts"))
      16 |   const Unsubscribe= onSnapshot(q, 
          (querySnapshot) => {
            //error is here in this line
    > 17 |     console.log("Data", querySnapshot.docs.map(d 
             => doc.data()));
         | ^  18 |   });
      19 |   return Unsubscribe;
      20 | }, [])
```

please help if anybody knows why is it happening
when I start this, the app runs for a second, and then this error pops up.

Comment: The error message is telling you that `doc` does not have a method called "data" on it.   We can't see what `doc` is, given what you've shared so far.  It would help if you edit the question to explain what you're trying to achieve here and enough code that we understand what everything is.

Comment: It should be either `.map(doc => ... ` or `d.data()` in that map.